# What is the MKS equivalent of SVN Update?

Tags: svn, version-control, mks, mks-integrity

I am contracting at a company that uses MKS. I have used SVN in the past as well as Mercurial and Git but must use MKS currently(so far I can't seem to find any documentation on it or best practices).

I want to know what the equivalent of SVN Update in MKS is?   I have tried resynchronize but all too often when I do that MKS wants to overwrite files that I have been working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're working on source, you have to 'Check Out/F2' the file first.  I assume you didn't do that?  If not, you'll have to move your work somewhere else, check out the file and then copy your work back over the checked out version.  Then you can check it back in.

#### Note that you'll have to create a change package first, this is what all of your 'Check Outs' will be done against.  After all the changes are done, you'll need to submit the Change Package.

Comment: So here is the part that makes me scratch my head.   I right click a file in explorer and when the menu comes up I select MKS Source Integrity -> Checkout.  I then edit the file using Notepad++ and save my modifications.  I then open up MKS find my sandbox and right click on the project file and select "Resynchronize".  When I do this MKS pops up a Window saying the working file "" has been modified.  Are you sure you wish to overwrite it?   There is no option to merge the file when I look at the differences it shows that no one has edited since I edited it.  This is what doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't have the MKS integrated into my explorer, I run the MKS Source standalone (with a sandbox).  I create a change package and then check files out as I need to work on them - they are read-only until this point - and, when I'm done with my mods, I submit the change package.  This is quite a different paradigm from your usage of the same product.  (I don't have an MKS options in explorer at all)

Answer (score 4):

When you "resynchronize" in MKS, the default behavior is to overwrite any working files in your sandbox with their member revisions from the current branch (or trunk if no branch exists.)

You can modify the behavior via configuration. In the client:

1. File->Edit Preferences
2. Expand the "MKS Source" tree node (2007) / "Configuration Management" tree node (2009)
3. Expand the "Commands" tree node
4. Select the "Resynchronize" command

You will want to modify the following settings

- Overwrite if Pending: **Uncheck**
- Overwrite Working File if Changed: **Uncheck**
- Overwrite if Deferred Operation Exists: **Uncheck**
- Merge Working File if Changed: **Check**
- Merge Type: **Automatic**
- On Conflicts: **Launch Tool**

The "resync" command will now attempt to automatically merge the member revision into your working file. If it cannot auto merge because of a conflict, it will launch the merge app to allow you to resolve the conflict.

I used SVN and CVS prior to using MKS, and I've found this modified resync behavior to be more intuitive than the standard resync behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The MKS command of SVN update is "lock member" then "check in" using the MKS Integrity client 2007 or 2009.
Cheers,
Ramil